# Not sure where my logic error for my password checker is

Tags: java, logic

So for my homework assignment we are needing to make a password checker that a user can use to login to the program and says whether they are using the valid or invalid credentials.

So I have tried to compare it to all my password variants and even tried comparing it to the exact string that is the password in the file but it still dosen't seem to work and I cant to seem to find where my logic is failing within it.

My authentication program where the user enters in their username and password.:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Authenticator extends JPanel{
//Windows Components
private JFrame window = new JFrame("Login");
private JLabel lblUser = new JLabel("Username:");
private JLabel lblPass = new JLabel("Password:");
private JLabel lblCorrect = new JLabel("Correct Login Credentials");
private JLabel lblWrong = new JLabel("Incorrect Login Credentials");
private JTextField txtUser = new JTextField();
private JPasswordField txtPass= new JPasswordField();
private JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");

//TODO:  Create an instance of the PasswordChecker
private PasswordChecker check = new PasswordChecker();

//Constructor: Sets up the window
public Authenticator(){
  //Absolute layout requires null
  setLayout(null);  

  //Sets x, y, w, h of each component 
  lblUser.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 30);
  lblPass.setBounds(10, 50, 200, 30);
  txtPass.setBounds(120, 50, 200, 30);
  txtUser.setBounds(120, 10, 200, 30);
  lblCorrect.setBounds(10, 100, 200, 30);
  lblWrong.setBounds(10, 100, 200, 30);
  btnLogin.setBounds(220, 100, 100, 30);


  //add components to panel
  add(lblUser);
  add(lblPass);
  add(txtUser);
  add(txtPass);
  add(lblCorrect);
  add(lblWrong);
  add(btnLogin);

  lblCorrect.setVisible(false);
  lblWrong.setVisible(false);

  //Adds panel to window
  window.add(this);
  //Closes the program when window closes
  window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  window.setSize(400, 250);
  window.setVisible(true);

  btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        String userName = txtUser.getText();
        String passWord = txtUser.getText();
        if(check.checkLogin(userName, passWord)){  
           lblCorrect.setVisible(true);    
        }//end if
        else{
           lblWrong.setVisible(true);
        }//end else




       }
  }); 

}//Ends constructor

public static void main(String args[]){
  new Authenticator();
}
}
```

This is my Password checker that checks the user input and should compare what the user input to the authenticator:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class PasswordChecker{
private ArrayList<String> user = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> pass = new ArrayList<>();


//Constructor: load the lists with the stuff from the file
public PasswordChecker(){

  String filename = "Logins.txt";
  Scanner fileIn;

  try{
     fileIn = new Scanner(new FileReader(filename));
     while(fileIn.hasNext()){
        user.add( fileIn.next() );
        pass.add( fileIn.next() );
     }
     fileIn.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }//ends catch
}//ends constructor

//GetPassword
public String getPassword(String userName){
  for(int i = 0; i < user.size(); i++){
     if(user.get(i).equals(userName)){
        String password = pass.get(i);
        return password;
     }//end if
  }//end for
  return userName;
 }//end getPassword



 //Check Login
 public boolean checkLogin(String userName, String password){

  for(String s: user){
     String uName = s;
     String pWord = getPassword(s);

        if(pWord == password){
           return true;
        }//end if




  }//end while
  return false;
 }//end checkLogin


}//ends Class
```

Im expecting my password checker to send a true or false statement that my authenticator to input whether or not they have the right details.

In my Logins.txt i have my usernames and password similar to this.
UserName PassWord
123 123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, string comparisons are done with the method `String.equals`.
In the line `if(pWord == password)` you used the equality operator `==` which checks only if two references point to the same object.
I would change `if(pWord == password)` to `if(pWord.equals(password))`.
**NOTE**
Java uses a caching system for strings, so sometimes using `==` might yield true but this is not always the case.

Comment: Wow i cant believe I overlooked that. Thank you. Cleared it right up and fixed that problem. Sometimes a new set of eyes helps(also someone who knows more)